# Why do I get an error in Chrome when I try to preview my LESS CSS stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, less

I am starting to use the LESS CSS stylesheet language to write my CSS.

This is what I have in the HTML file

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less" />
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.18.min.js"> </script>
```

The problem that I am facing is that every time I am previewing my website in Chrome, I receive this error:

```
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I understand that I will need to compile my .less file into a .css file for browsers to read, but I should be able to at least **preview** my website, right?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you are reading your HTML document directly from your local file system. Don't. Install a web server locally and use that for testing. It will more accurately reflect the final live environment (where URIs beginning with `/` and lots of security features work differently).

Comment: Yes! I am indeed reading my HTML document directly from my local fiel system. So, something like MAMP will allow it to work?

Comment: Yes. Any HTTP server will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers will block ajax calls coming from html documents on the file:// protocol for "security", have you tried putting this on a server? [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) are good for testing on your local device.

Comment: I'm gonna stop double checking links before I post, sniped again ;)

Comment: The problem is file vs http, not "plain HTML".